# Is there something wrong with this email function?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have written a function to send a confirmation email for a hobby app I am working on. I thought I set everything up properly, but I am getting the following error when I call the function:

`` 2019-05-08 02:43:30 Connection failed. Error #2: failed loading cafile stream: `C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt' [C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\InviteMe Application\vendor\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 405]
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. ``

I have already set up my gmail account to allow less secure apps to access the account and I have a password generated.

I have tried reading the troubleshooting documentation for the library I am using but have not been able to find anything that addresses the specific problem I am having.

Here is the email function:

```
function send_confirmation_email($name, $email, $user_id) {
    $confirmationUrl = generate_confirmation_url($user_id);
    $body = "";
    $body .= "<html><body>";
    $body .="<h1>Confirm your account</h1>";
    $body .= "<p>Follow the link below to confirm your account:</p>";
    $body .= "<a href='" . $confirmationUrl . "'>confirm account</a>";

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3; //debugging purposes
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "invitemedemo@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "password";
    $mail->setFrom('invitemedemo@gmail.com', "InviteMe");
    $mail->addAddress($email, $name);
    $mail->Subject = "Confirm Account";
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->isHTML(true);

    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Rather than the email being sent, I see the error I pasted above.

Comment: I know that the script is failing to connect to the SMTP server. I just can't understand why.

Comment: Does the CA cert (`C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt`) exist? Is it valid?

Comment: if you are in local, the phpmailer class may not work , so test it on host and of it was there , contact your hosting provider ...

Comment: What @Raptor said, and read what the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide has to say about CA certificate bundles.

Comment: The CA cert should be valid. I downloaded the files directly from the repo. I have a feeling that this might all be caused by me creating a new scope and the methods inside the new function scope being unable to access properties outside it.

Answer (score -2):

Validate your smtp email service.

If you have MAC OS, see how to enable postfix for Gmail SMTP using your gmail account at: https://gist.github.com/loziju/66d3f024e102704ff5222e54a4bfd50e

Using Ubuntu Linux reference: https://gist.github.com/adamstac/7462202

Check the PHP settings in the php.ini file for the active php version you are using.
i.e. Using MAMP for MAC OS, gt to Applications -> MAMP -> conf -> php7.0.32 (must be the active version you are using, so if you are using php 5.3.14, then go to that directory) ->php.ini

Edit the php.ini file with:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well 
(default: "sendmail -t -i").
;sendmail_path = sendmail -t -i -f example@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "env -i /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -I"
```

Restart apache2 after updating the php.ini file.

If using MAC OS to stop and restart mail service: sudo postfix stop && sudo postfix start sudo postfix reload

Test Email
Send a test email from the terminal CLI:

```
echo "Test sending email from Postfix" | mail -s "Test Postfix" example@gmail.com
```

Alternatively, I find I can send a test message from the terminal CLI using this:

```
echo "test message" | sendmail -v example@gmail.com
```

Check errors for sendmail use the terminal CLI command:

```
mailq
```

You can test the SMTP feature using php such as:

```
<?php
    // testemail.php
    $to_email = 'example@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Testing PHP Mail';
    $message = 'This mail is sent using the PHP mail function';
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
    $headers = 'From: yoursending@email.com';
    mail($to_email,$subject,$message,$headers);
    $mail = mail($to_email,$subject,$message,$headers);
    if ($mail) { echo "Thank you for using mail";}
    else { echo "Mail sending failed.";}
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
?>
```

Comment: That's **not** related at all. 1. OP is using XAMPP, not MAMP. 2. OP is using Windows, not Linux (therefore no Postfix, no sendmail). 3. OP's problem is the network connection to SMTP host due to unable to load CA cert.